# TypeError: Cannot read property 'simpleResponse' of undefined at DialogflowConversation.response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

So I have gotten TypeErrors many times before when playing with actions-on-google and dialogflow, however, this property is from what I can understand not in my code  but rather in "DialogflowConversation". Therefore i can't understand what possibly could be undefined...

Here is the rest of the error message:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'simpleResponse' of undefined
at DialogflowConversation.response (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.js:261:25)
at DialogflowConversation.serialize (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/conv.js:159:129)
at Function.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:157:
at next (native)
at fulfilled (/user_code/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/service/dialogflow/dialogflow.js:19:58)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)"
```

Comment: That code is called after processing your intent handler as it prepares a reply. Can you post your intent handler that was called that triggered that error? It does seem quite odd.

Comment: If you mean the fulfillment code for the intent, then that is way to much to post since there is a lot of API calls and logic, however I can tell you that my response is of type SimpleResponse. What more specific information can I provide?